# Bash: accessing another users documents

Tags: linux, grep

Using bash scripting I am trying to access another's users documents and search for a word in a file, how would I do this?

Comment: Well, you need permissions to do so.

Comment: Yes, `grep ~otherUser/foo.txt "bar baz quirk"` should do the trick.

Comment: @H2CO3, no, first the pattern, then the file...

Comment: @sputnick Yes, right, I always confuse that...

Answer (score 0):

try this command-:

```
grep 'word' file
```

Comment: I know how to search the file, but I don't know how I would be able to access a file on another user's account?

Comment: Basically I want to change directory but to another users account how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you *allowed* to do this?

First, you need to know where their home directory is.  Let's say their name is `bob`.  You can use the short-hand syntax `cd ~bob` to set the working directory to their home.

You will need to have sufficient privileges to do so.  That means there must be read and execute permissions on that folder for 'all users' *or* for their group (if you are also in that group).  The same applies to sub-directories and files that you wish to access.

As long as you have permissions, this is just a matter of locating and grepping the file.

If you don't have permissions, then you need to login as someone who does.  That is likely to be the `root` or `bob`.  I gather you do not have access to either of those accounts.  I also wonder about your intent.  You could always **ask** 'Bob' if he can make the file accessible to you.